# New programmer needs code to open changing filename, delete text and save to same filename

Tags: wildcard, save, editing

I literally know nothing about Perl but am trying to write code to delete characters within a .xml file using Perl 5.  Here is what I need to do:

1. The filename will change every day.  For example:  MyFile_yyyymmddhrmnsc.xml (where yyyy=year; mm=month; dd=day; hr=hour; mn=minutes; sc=seconds).  Using a wildcard to designate what changes each day in the filename: MyFile_*.xml
2. Within the file, I want to change all instances of "Job xmlns" to "Job"
3. I want to save the changes to the same XML filename

I hope my explanation is sufficient but if not - please let me know.  I realize this might not be the place to ask this - if not, could you please direct me to where I could get information?

Comment: If you know literally nothing about Perl, why haven't you tried to teach yourself at least _something_ before asking this question, and why Perl?

Comment: @lindasabo: You might find this tutorial a better start. http://www.techrepublic.com/article/parsing-xml-documents-with-perls-xmlsimple/5363190

Comment: I have been going through some tutorials.  I was able to write a successful basic Perl prog to delete text in a .txt file and save it to the same file - but when I made it a .xml file - everything in the file disappeared.  Then I tried using a wildcard (*) to open the filename and Perl did not like that at all.  Why Perl - because it was recommended.